# Executing hadoopfs in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

I trying to run a bash script of the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_HDFS_PATH=`hadoopfs -ls -t -r /$CLEAN_HDFS_PATH | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}'`
echo "Here is the last (most current) file in the history folder to be downloaded=$CURRENT_HDFS_PATH"
```

The above does not produce any result at all. Please note that CLEAN_HDFS_PATH=/temp/local-*.inprogress

When I use the following in command line:

```
hadoopfs -ls -t -r  '/temp/local-*.inprogress' | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}'
```

I get the answer from the command line.

What am I doing wrong in my script ?

Cheers,

Comment: Did you export CLEAN_HDFS_PATH?

Comment: I did not. It is a variable assigned inside the script. The code above is a snippet.

Comment: Put a `set -x` at the top of the script and see how it interprets the line `CURRENT_HDFS_PATH ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of the file literally `local-*.inprogress`? If so, your problem is wildcard expansion within script. Add double quotes around the variable and see if that works like:

```
CURRENT_HDFS_PATH=`hadoopfs -ls -t -r "/$CLEAN_HDFS_PATH" | tail -1 | awk -F ' ' '{print $8}'`
```